# Grails findAll and GroupBy

Tags: grails, groovy, group-by, findall

I have a domain class with 3 fields: name, age and city. I would like to find all with constraint on age and group by city. This is my code so far:

```
import groovy.transform.*
@Canonical
class Person{
    String name
    int age
    String city
} 
List<Person> list = [
    new Person('Jey', 42, 'New'),
    new Person('Leo', 25, 'New'),
    new Person('Dan', 29, 'New'),
    new Person('Alex', 36, 'Fran'),
    new Person('Doe', 34, 'Lon'),
    new Person('Tim', 34, 'Lon'),
    new Person('Jin', 34, 'Lon'),
    new Person('Bob', 34, 'Par'),  
    new Person('Ken', 37, 'Par'),    
]
groupByCity = list.findAll{it.age < 36}.groupBy{it.city}.collectEntries{key, value -> [(key): [value.age, value.name]]}
println groupByCity
```

What I need is:

```
[New:[[25,Leo], [29, Dan]], Lon:[[34, Doe], [34, Tim]..
```

or

```
 [New:[[25:Leo], [29: Dan]], Lon:[[34: Doe], [34: Tim]..
```

but I got

```
 [New:[[25, 29], [Leo, Dan]], Lon:[[34, 34, 34], [Doe, Tim, Jin]], Par:[[34], [Bob]]]
```

The context : I want to extract objects from domain class group by field and show two send those lists to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the value is a list and `[value.age, value.name]` results in `[[25, 29], [Leo, Dan]] ..`.

Add a collect call to extract the desired result -

```
list
.findAll{it.age < 36}
.groupBy{it.city}
.collectEntries{key, value -> [(key): value.collect{ [it.age, it.name] }]}
```